# Using prf file to configure outlook clients

Tags: outlook-2003

I have a prf file to outlook clients. For the moment the new exchange will be in another domain, that will change in the future. But the usernames on both domains are the same.

I see that the example prf just takes the username

```
;***************************************************************
; Section 4 - Default values for each service.
;***************************************************************

[ServiceEGS]
MailboxName=%UserName%
HomeServer=exchange_server_name

[Service1]
OverwriteExistingService=No
UniqueService=Yes
MailboxName=%UserName%
HomeServer=exchange_server_name
AccountName=Microsoft Exchange Server
```

Can I add the domainname to that like so.

```
MailboxName=\\domain\%UserName´%
```

or is there a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the mailbox name is generally the exchange alias; the email address should work too.

But why would you want to do this?  If the usernames are the same on both domains, then the server you're pointing to is going to dictate which domain they're authenticating against -- there's no reason to include the domain in the username.

Comment: you are so right, I think I had a brain cramp.